# Update field with jquery don't update observable

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to say hello to the stackoverflow community.

I've just started using knockout a few days ago.

Right know I'm using it to make a dynamic menu builder for a CMS I'm working on.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/dnlgmzddr/HcRqn/

The problem is that when I choose an element from the select box, the input field update as I expect, but the observable doesn't reflect the change. Because of that, the add button is not enabled.

What am I missing? How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you populate the url field, you would need to trigger the change event to get the observable to be upated.  So, you could do:

```
$("#url").val('/pages/' + id).change();
```

Another option though that is more in the Knockout spirit is to use a binding on your select.  In this case, you would likely want to populate an observable with that value, then use a manual subscription to default the formatted value into the input field.

```
this.itemUrl = ko.observable();
this.selectedUrl = ko.observable();
this.selectedUrl.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
        this.itemUrl("/pages/" + newValue);                
    }
}, this);
```

Then, bind your select to `selectedUrl`:

```
    <select id="pagedList" data-bind="value: selectedUrl">
        <option value=""><option>
        <option value="test">Test</option>
    </select>
```

Here is a sample:  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/HcRqn/21/

You could also eliminate the extra observable and manual subscription if the "value" of your options was the url.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anywhere in your code where you are actually enabling the button when a field is selected. So I might be missing something, but just enable the button on change. Like the following:

```
function LoadMenu() {
    $("#pagedList").change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $("#url").val('/pages/' + id);
        // remove the disabled attribute here
        $('button.space').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
}
```